# Inline or block using chrome developer tools?

Tags: html, google-chrome, developer-tools

Can we figure out whether an HTML element is inline or block using chrome developer tools?

Answer (score 1):

"inline" and "block" aren't hugely useful categories to use in the first place.

In HTML 4 they were terms used in the DTD to [group elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/dtd.html#inline) for quickly describing which elements could contain which other elements (and they often had exceptions).

In HTML 5 DTDs are gone and there are [a different set of groups](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#content-models) for elements.

**There's no way to get the HTML categorisation of an element from the developer tools.**

(At least not by default. Someone could put together a list of elements and how they are categorised in the specification and then write a developer tools plugin to display that information for the selected element. I'm not aware of anyone who has or why anyone would bother though.)

---

Meanwhile in CSS, `display` and `block` are two of the [original values for the `display` property](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS1/#display). Almost all elements used to default to displaying as one or the other.

Today there are [many more values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) as the specification has been rewritten to have (for example) `display: inline-block` instead of depending on exceptions to the rendering rules and new layout tools have been added like `display: grid`.

**You can determine the `display` value for an element by looking in the *Computed* panel.**

[image: The Computed Panel]